# Вырезать определенную части из строки

Tags: javascript, php, python

посредством post-запроса получаю файл, используя:

```
file_get_contents('php://input');
```

выводя принятые данные в файл  - заметил, что в начале каждой строки стоит имя файла, пример отправляю файл index.html и получаю следующее, после urldecode():

```
index.html=<!DOCTYPE html>
&index.html=<html>
&index.html=    <head>
&index.html=        <title>TEST</title>
&index.html=    </head>
&index.html=    <body>
&index.html=        
&index.html=        <p> TEST HTML CODE</p>
&index.html=
&index.html=    </body>
&index.html=</html>
```

Вопрос в том, как удалить эти метки "$index.html=" чтобы оставить исходный текст?

Comment: А кто добавляет эти строки `&index.html`, я как понимаю если не добавлять эти строки то не нужно будет их удалять :(

Comment: Не знаю, судя по-всему это происходит при отправке запроса

Comment: удалять "метки" не надо. надо их не отправлять. Для этого нужно видеть, как и что вы отправляете. и выводите